# how can I edit a Java application using .CLASS files

Tags: java, .class-file

I've been trying to edit the `.CLASS` files inside this program using `.jar` containers, and a `.bat` file to launch it.

I'm not familiar with Java, and I've tried Java decompilers but they don't let me edit the source, only copy it. I don't seem to have a program that can actually correctly save and encode it.

What's the best option here to easily edit this Java program's `.CLASS` files?

Edit: To everyone who's enjoying downrepping this, the program is open source and permits modifications. So thank you for all the blame flinging about it being illegal.

Comment: What kind of edit you would make on .class?

Comment: Google: "edit class java".

Comment: It's a basic watermarking program and I want to change some default settings to speed up the process of its usage. I don't know why everyone's jumping to law breaking.

Comment: @JavaNewbie_M107 It's not, actually. As the name "Copyright" implies, it applies to distribution (copying). In some countries it may be illegal to decompile code, I personally don't live in one of them.

Comment: @JavaNewbie_M107 Not necessarily. For example, in germany, there are conditions under which you are explicitly allowed to reverse engineer software. Also, you might just want to fix a bug.

Comment: @questy Have you written this watermarking program?

Comment: No, I haven't. I just want to change default settings like opacity, image quality, etc. to my preferences.

Answer (score 4):

You could try decompiling it with Fernflower, editing the code, then compiling it back into a classfile with the normal javac.

Answer (score 1):

There is no real "easy" way. You could edit the bytecode...but that is a bit more involved. You can use JD but, that as you said, is only so useful.

Answer (score 1):

Use [java de-compliler](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui) to get source code from byte code, modify as per you want save in different location(like copy source code with your modifications) then compile & run.